# Using .replace() with a conditional group

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex (shown below) that works exactly how I'd like it to work, except I'd only like to insert the `'x'` if group `$7` exists.

Is there a way to do this using `.replace()`?

`phoneNumber.replace(/(\()?(\d{3})(\))? ?(\d{3})-?(\d{4})( +)?(\d+)?/, '($2) $4-$5 x$7');`

Sample Input: 
`7777777777`

Output for Sample Input:
`(777) 777-7777 x`

Update:

Thank you @Amit Joki for the callback.

In the end this was what I used:

Note: The regex needed to be updated to include the `x` that was inserted by the callback.

```
phoneNumber.replace(/(\()?(\d{3})(\))? ?(\d{3})-?(\d{4})([ x]+)?(\d+)?/, 
    function(m, g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6, g7) {
        return "(" + g2 + ")" + " " + g4 + "-" + g5 + (g7 ? " x" + g7 : "");
    }
);
```

Comment: provide a sample input along with expected output.

Comment: The sample input/output has been added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use callback for that.

```
phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace(/(\()?(\d{3})(\))? ?(\d{3})-?(\d{4})( +)?(\d+)?/, 
function(m, g1, g2, g3, g4, g5,g6,g7) { // matches
    return "(" + g2 + ")" + g4 + "-" + g5 + (g7 ? "x" : "");
});
```

The conditional part is `g7 ? "x" : ""` which is a ternary operator which returns `"x"` if `g7` exists else empty string `""`

[**Check out more on callback function on MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)